# How to roll a 3D array N times and keep all the rolled versions without loops?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, binary

I'm working with a binary array `G` in NumPy, which is structured as follows:

```py
G = np.array([
    [
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
    ],
    [
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
    ]
])
```

I’m looking for a way to roll this array **`N`** times and keep each rolled version. For instance, if **`N = 3`**, the output should look like this:

```
output = array([
    [
        [
            [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ],
        [
            [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ],
        [
            [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ],
        [
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ],
        [
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
        ]
    ]
])
```

Comment: in case you do not care about boundaries: [Sliding window view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)

Answer (score 0):

```py
# duplicate each axis-0 subarray N times
output = np.repeat(G, N, axis=0)

# your output requires adding a dimension to group the new
# rotated subarrays together
output = output.reshape(G.shape[0], N, *G.shape[1:])

# rotate each new subarray
for i in range(N):
    output[:,i] = np.roll(output[:,i], i, axis=2)
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply , but it still uses a loop